# <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> not found in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

Hello I am trying to include Parse into my iOS application but unfortunately there were a lot changes made in iOS 9.

I have downloaded the Parse starter project and have Parse up and running and have also included the Facebook SDK in my project, but my problem I have is in my "PFFacebookUtils.h". It keeps giving me and error saying that " file not found".

[image]

These are all the libraries I have. Under ParseFacebookUtils.framework there is a file named PFFacebookUtils.h, I get that  file not found" in there. Does anyone have any experience with using Facebook and Parse for iOS 9? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the **ParseFacebookUtils.framework** from your project :)
Another(better) way is to use cocoapods and you'll forget about such problems.

Comment: I think I need that framework to initialize Facebook and login with Facebook. I don't think you can remove it.

Comment: Remove ParseFacebookUtils.framework and add ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework - this work with last FBSDK

Comment: Yep! Just did that lurie. I then imported #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h> wherever I needed PFFacebookUtils. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Also in my picture if you can see the three red libraries, I replaced them with libz.tbd, libsqlite3.tbd, and libz.1.1.3.tbd. Do you know the difference between tbd and dylib. In the quick start guide for parse they told me to add libz.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib. But the .dylib was not there in the link binaries but it was replaced by .tbd.